# Execute function in vscode snippet

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, plugins, vscode-snippets

Is it possible to run a function during expansion of snippet?

**javascript.json - vscode snippet file:**

```
function add() {
    return 2+2;
}

"Print to console": {
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": [
        "console.log("Addition", add());"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
}
```

**index.js - project file:**

```
// I wrote "log" and intellisense currently provides
console.log("Addition", add());

// But I need
console.log("Addition", 4);
```

The obvious reason might be snippet is a json file, it's not a javascript file so it can't run code, just show syntax as it with cursor positions $1, $2 etc.

Or is it possible through a vscode plugin?

Comment: use the `Hypersnips` extension

Comment: thanks @rioV8 I achieved the desired result, and post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *Hypersnips* vscode extension as suggested by *rioV8*, I've a working hsnips which might help you.

**all.hsnips OR javascript.hsnips:**

```
global
function add() {
  return 2+2;
}
endglobal

snippet log "Log output to console"
``
rv = `console.log("Addition", ${add()})`
``
endsnippet
```